# Warning C4710 (not inlined) with inherited destructors

Tags: c++, inheritance, inline, destructor, compiler-warnings

I have 3 classes that build a chain of inheritance. Two of the classes are pure abstract (IProxy and IDataProxy), the third one really "does the work" (DataProxy). The classes are the following (only showing con/destructors here):

IProxy:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) IProxy
{
public:
    IProxy() {}
    virtual ~IProxy() {}
};
```

IDataProxy:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) IDataProxy : public IProxy
{
public:
    IDataProxy() {}
    virtual ~IDataProxy() {}
};
```

DataProxy Header:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) DataProxy : public IDataProxy
{
public:
    DataProxy();
    virtual ~DataProxy() {}
};
```

DataProxy Implementation file:

```
DataProxy::DataProxy() : m_operationType( eUnknown )
{}
```

When I compile the class DataProxy with Microsoft C++ compiler (version 12.00.8804) I get the following warnings:

`warning C4710: function 'virtual __thiscall IDataProxy::~IDataProxy(void)' not inlined

warning C4710: function 'virtual __thiscall IDataProxy::~IDataProxy(void)' not inlined

warning C4710: function 'virtual __thiscall DataProxy::~DataProxy(void)' not inlined

warning C4710: function 'virtual __thiscall DataProxy::~DataProxy(void)' not inlined`

I don't really know where these warnings com from. I never told the compiler to inline anything. And I don't have any idea how to get rid of these warnings.

Can anyone shed some light on these warnings? Thanks a lot!

Best regards,
    Oliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By defining the constructors inside the class, you implicitly add the `inline` specifier. Virtual functions (including destructors) are not inlined.

However the warning most certainly comes from the fact that a `dllexport` function must have a given (`thiscall`) calling convention and therefore will never be inlined. Virtual member functions *can* be inlined if they are called non polymorphically. This will never be the case here.

@MSalters 's comment provides a hint to why the warning does not occur for `IProxy::~IProxy()`.

To get rid of the warning, define your empty destructors in the source file.

Comment: IDataProxy is a pure abstract class, supposed to define an interface. I don't really want to have a cpp file for a pure abstract class, do I?
And why doesn't the warning occur for the class IProxy?

Comment: `IProxy::~IProxy` doesn't do anything. `IDataProxy::~IDataProxy` calls `IProxy::~IProxy`, which is a DLL export and therefore cannot be optimized out.

Comment: Then why do you have it declared DLL export, when all it contains is two inlined functions? If you want to have them in the DLL, there must reasonably be some .cpp file.

Comment: Or if he doesn't care about inlining in this compilation unit but wishes to get them in other, use `#pragma warning(disable 4710)`

Answer (score 0):

By providing the implementation of the destructors in the class, you are asking to inline them.  This is also true for constructors and members functions.

Answer (score -2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd3056cz(v=VS.100).aspx

This link clearly explains everything you need to know. It clearly states what the warning is, why it occurs, and that the warning is off by default. Class member functions are implicitly inline if defined inline. A little effort before asking a question is generally required- such as searching your compiler's documentation for the warning number.

Comment: The real concern of OP is that he did not explicitly ask for inlining. This MSDN article (and the link it provides) does not answer this.

Comment: The question asks about shedding light on the warning. The link sheds *all* the light.

Comment: In fact I read this MSDN article, but from the facts given there did not understand what my error was. What I also don't understand: Why do I get the error for IDataProxy and DataProxy but not for IProxy? Isn't the structure of all three classes identical with regards to the destructor?

Comment: @Alexandre C.: The OP did ask for inlining by providing the function bodies **inline** in the body of the class. Doing that is as if you have provided explicit `inline` keyword.